# php get the text into an array list

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in the database. When I used print_r($variable_name), I got the array like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [attribute_name] => Disk space,Color,Processor
            )

    )
```

So to get the value of attribute_name I tried this

```
foreach($attributes_name as $key=>$val) {
      echo $val['attribute_name'];
    }
```

Here I got the result like `Disk space,Color,Processor`. But I want the result should come like a list

```
<li>Disk Space</li> 
<li>Color</li>
<li>Processor</li>
```

So can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$arr = array(array("attribute_name" => "Disk space,Color,Processor"));

foreach($arr as $val) {
    $resultArr = explode(",",$val['attribute_name']);
    foreach($resultArr as $value){
        echo "<li>".$value."</li>";

        // Add id in li
        echo "<li id='".str_replace(" ","_", strtolower($value))."'>".$value."</li>";
    }
}
?>
```